# Do I need to escape echo'd strings for console output?

Tags: php, shell

I can't decide whether I'm being overly paranoid here, but if I'm running a PHP script from a commandline and that script echo's out user defined content, do I need to escape it?

For example, would this be potentially dangerous or would the text literally just echo out as plain text?

```
$test = 'shutdown -h now';
echo $test;
```

If I do need to escape, is it the escapeshellarg() function I want?

Comment: Yes. You should, if you pass user defined params to `exec()` or `shell_exec()`.

Comment: The question is explicitly stated to be about `echoing out user defined content`, nothing about any `exec()` or such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell interpretes commands from stdin but you are writing to stdout. So everything is fine

However, to prevent you from accidently copy pasting them into a terminal it is never a bad idea to escape them

Comment: Thanks hek2mgl, that makes sense =). I guess I'm just overthinking things again!

Comment: @Ric np :) Also note the answer from ComFreek. Some sequences could break your terminal output

Answer (score 3):

I do not fully agree with the other answers.

It is right that you write to stdout, so the input won't be interpreted as commands, **but** some special control sequences can invoke some shell-related behaviour. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121282/why-do-my-keystrokes-turn-into-crazy-characters-after-i-dump-a-bunch-of-binary-d), for example.

These cannot call other programs or commands, but they can annoy the user (he has to type `reset` for resseting the shell).

Comment: Interesting... how would you protect against this, ComFreek? exec('reset'); at the end perhaps?

Comment: @Ric `exec('reset');` sounds nice! I currently see no other way if you are outputting random data (beside from manually escaping them)

Comment: @Ric I think escaping is not as complex as one might think. These characters should be very easy to catch in the string stream. I am not an expert on this topic, so I cannot give any further advices. This link might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534556/how-do-we-remove-and-all-of-the-escape-sequences-in-a-file-using-linux-shell

Comment: @hek2mgl Doesn't `reset` reset the whole terminal? The output would be cleared then.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be dangerous. User can't invoke any command this way. Of course if you are not using `exec()` or similar function in between. Please note that passing any argument to phpcli from command line is dangerous. Because this argument may contain "`", that executes the command in shell to get a result.