# Keystrokes disappearing in terminal when using Play framework

Tags: playframework

I recently downloaded Play using homebrew. The first time I did this the brew formula downloaded an older version of Play. I modified the formula to download the most recent version (2.2.0) and it successfully downloaded. However, I have had a few issues with the download.

First, I kept getting an error when invoking play from the terminal: "Unable to access jarfile ../Cellar/play2/2.0-RC3/bin/framework/sbt/sbt-launch.jar". I searched online and found a solution in this [forum](http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/194). I edited my play file per the suggestion of someone on the forum. My play file now looks like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env sh


#PRG="$0"
# resolve relative/absolute symlinks
#while [ -h "$PRG" ] ; do
 # ls=`ls -ld "$PRG"`
   #link=`expr "$ls" : '.*-> \(.*\)$'`
  #if expr "$link" : '/.*' > /dev/null; then
   # PRG="$link"
  #else
   # PRG="`dirname "$PRG"`/$link"
  #fi
#done
#dir=`dirname $0` && dir=$dir/`dirname $PRG`

# Extract possibly relative directory to invoked file
RDIR="$(dirname "$0")"

# Convert to absolute directory
ADIR="$(cd "$RDIR"; pwd)"

# PRG is now absolute path to invoked file
PRG="$ADIR/$(basename "$0")"

# Resolve symlink(s)
while [ -h "$PRG" ] ; do
  PRG=`readlink "$PRG"`
done

if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
  JAVA="java"
else
 JAVA="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
fi

# dir is the absolute dir of the resolved link(s)
dir=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; cd "$(dirname "$PRG")"; pwd)

if [ -f conf/application.conf -o -f conf/reference.conf ] || [ -d project ]; then
  if test "$1" = "clean-all"; then
    rm -rf target
    rm -rf tmp
    rm -rf logs
    rm -rf dist
    rm -rf project/project
    rm -rf project/target
    if [ $# -ne 1 ]
    then  
     shift
    else
      echo "[info] Done!"
      exit 0
    fi
  fi
  if test "$1" = "stop"; then
    if [ -f RUNNING_PID ]; then
      echo "[info] Stopping application (with PID `cat RUNNING_PID`)..."
      kill `cat RUNNING_PID`

      RESULT=$?

      if test "$RESULT" = 0; then
        echo "[info] Done!"
        exit 0
      else
        echo "[\033[31merror\033[0m] Failed ($RESULT)"
        exit $RESULT
      fi
    else
      echo "[\033[31merror\033[0m] No RUNNING_PID file. Is this application running?"
      exit 1
    fi
  fi

  if test "$1" = "debug"; then
    JPDA_PORT="9999"
    shift      
  fi

  if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    JPDA_PORT="${JPDA_PORT}" $dir/../libexec/framework/build "$@"
  else
    JPDA_PORT="${JPDA_PORT}" $dir/../libexec/framework/build play
  fi

else
  "$JAVA" -Dplay.home=$dir/../libexec/framework -Dsbt.boot.properties=$dir/../libexec/framework/sbt/play.boot.properties ${PLAY_OPTS} -jar $dir/../libexec/framework/sbt/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
fi
```

This was a great solution and solved my problem. However, now I have another issue I am not able to solve.

When I invoke play from the terminal all works well, until I start typing again. My keystrokes do not show up! I found a work around (type 'reset') solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121282/why-do-my-keystrokes-turn-into-crazy-characters-after-i-dump-a-bunch-of-binary-d), so I can continue working.

My question is why do my keystrokes disappear and what can I do to fix it? Please let me know if there is additional information needed. I am on Mac OS X Version 10.7.5.

Comment: I have the same problem with disappearing keystrokes in the terminal. Play probably disables the terminal echo command and does not reset it.
The "typing reset in the terminal window" works, but it may be a bug in the play framework
Mac OS X 10.9
Play Framework 2.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known bug:
[Play 2.2 Bash/Shell Bug #1815](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/1815)

A fix was submitted and merged but it's not out in a stable release yet. I think it should be in the latest RC2 release if it's really bugging you.

If I remember correctly, the problem only happens when you do `play start` or `play run`. If you first go into the SBT shell and then give your start/run command then it works fine. I could be misremembering on that though.

Answer (score 0):

Just blindly type reset in the terminal window.

peterpilgrim@Peters-MBP.local [506] > peterpilgrim@Peters-MBP.local [506] >peterpilgrim@Peters-MBP.local [506] > [type reset and hit return a few times]